# How can I query the same column in a kdb table multiple times in a single statement?

Tags: kdb

I have the following table in kdb...

```
p:([]r:("(A|A(A|B|C|D).*)";"A(E|F|G|H|I).*";"A(J|K|L|M).*";"A(N|O|P|Q|R|S).*";"A(T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z).*";"B.*";"(C|C(A|B|C|D|E).*)";"C(F|G|H|I|J|K).*";"C(L|M|N|O|P|Q|R).*";"C(S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z).*";"D.*"))
r
----------------------
"(A|A(A|B|C|D).*)"
"A(E|F|G|H|I).*"
"A(J|K|L|M).*"
"A(N|O|P|Q|R|S).*"
"A(T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z).*"
"B.*"
"(C|C(A|B|C|D|E).*)"
"C(F|G|H|I|J|K).*"
"C(L|M|N|O|P|Q|R).*"
"C(S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z).*"
"D.*"
```

and the below function that parses each row of the table...

```
getRange:{$[x like "*(*";
  [if[x like "(*"; x2:1#1_x; l:enlist x2; x:-1_(3_x)];
  l,:enlist {(3#x),"-",(-3#x)} ssr[ssr[ssr[x;".";""];")";"]"];"(";"["];
  if[((count l)>1)&(l[1] like "*A-*"); l[1]:ssr[l[1]; "A-";"0-9/A-"]];
  :l];
  :enlist ssr[x;".";""]
  ];
 }
```

Which gives an output like this...

```
r1:raze getRange'[exec r from p]
q)r1
,"A"
"A[0-9/A-D]*"
"A[E-I]*"
"A[J-M]*"
"A[N-S]*"
"A[T-Z]*"
"B*"
,"C"
"C[0-9/A-E]*"
"C[F-K]*"
"C[L-R]*"
"C[S-Z]*"
"D*"
```

I'm parsing the rows so they can be inserted into a query similar to something like `select from t where sym like raze getRange'[exec r from p][0]`

What I'd like to be able to do is combine the first "single A" with the first "group of A" and the same with the C's (so it looks like below). But the problem I'm having is that those results can't be easily inserted into a query...

```
(,"A";"A[0-9/A-D]*")
,"A[E-I]*"
,"A[J-M]*"
,"A[N-S]*"
,"A[T-Z]*"
,"B*"
(,"C";"C[0-9/A-E]*")
,"C[F-K]*"
,"C[L-R]*"
,"C[S-Z]*"
,"D*"
```

Is there a way in q that I can do this? Essentially, `select from t where sym like (enlist "A";"A[0-9/A-D]*")`

Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching against multiple regexps we can do following

```
select from t where any sym like/:("A";"A[0-9/A-D]*")
```